# How do I dump messageQueue in a Handler?

Tags: java, android

I'm debugging an Android framework, a Handler handles message slow so I though maybe I should check the MessageQueue of the Handler to see if the message has a low priority or the queue is too long.

I looked in to the Handler.java and saw a dump method:

```
public final void dump (Printer pw, String prefix)
```

which finally calls the MessageQueue to dump all messages.

Here is the question, how should I use the dump, especially the prama Printer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Following will dump the queue to the system log (logcat). You can replace [LogPrinter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LogPrinter.html) with other implementation of [Printer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Printer.html). For example [StringBuilderPrinter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/StringBuilderPrinter.html) will send the output to a StringBuilder.

```
mHandler.dump(new LogPrinter(Log.DEBUG, "TAG"), "PREFIX");
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK added some explanation to my answer. New to stackoverflow so appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation of Printer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Printer.html). Use one of the referenced subclasses.